# Making collapsible GroupBoxes in Qt - what determines the collapsed size?

Tags: c++, qt, qgroupbox

I'm trying to make GroupBoxes with a Collapse/Expand button with a hopefully obvious function in Qt. I have subclassed QGroupBox with draws the button. When clicked, my code calls `setVisible(false)` on all children of the GroupBox. Additionally it goes over all QLayouts in the GroupBox and sets their contentMargins to zero. However, some GroupBoxes still come out larger than others in the collapsed state and I have no good idea what could cause this.

This is what I have come up with so far (I'm aware of the possible `nullptr` issue):

```
void CollapsibleGroupBox::onVisibilityChanged()
{
  CollapseExpandButton::State s;

  s = m_clExpButton->state();

  QLayout *master = this->layout();
  QList<QObject *> children = this->children();

  switch (s) {
  case CollapseExpandButton::State::COLLAPSED:
    for (QObject *o : children) {
      QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(o);
      if (w != nullptr) {
        if (w != m_clExpButton)
          w->setVisible(false);

        continue;
      }

      if (o == master) {
        m_layoutMargins.clear();
        collapseLayout(master);
      }
    }
    break;
  case CollapseExpandButton::State::EXPANDED:
    for (QObject *o : children) {
      QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(o);
      if (w != nullptr) {
        w->setVisible(true);

        continue;
      }

      if (o == master)
        expandLayout(master);

    }
    break;
  }
}


void CollapsibleGroupBox::collapseLayout(QLayout *layout)
{
  for (QObject *o : layout->children()) {
    QLayout *l= qobject_cast<QLayout *>(o);
    if (l == nullptr)
      continue;

    collapseLayout(l);
  }
  if (m_layoutMargins.contains(layout))
    return;

  QMargins m = layout->contentsMargins();
  m_layoutMargins[layout] = m;
  layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::expandLayout(QLayout *layout)
{
  for (QObject *o : layout->children()) {
    QLayout *l = qobject_cast<QLayout *>(o);
    if (l == nullptr)
      continue;

    if (m_layoutMargins.contains(l))
      expandLayout(l);
  }
  if (m_layoutMargins.contains(layout)) {
    QMargins m = m_layoutMargins[layout];
    layout->setContentsMargins(m);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried hiding the layout and not touching anything else? This should do the job of hiding all of the children.

Comment: Also, are you concerned about collapsed height or width? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: At this point I'm only concerned by height. The `QLayout` doesn't seem to have a `setVisible()` method.

Comment: As for screenshots:

Collapsed GroupBoxes with different sizes:
http://imgur.com/tg4jSAw

These widgets shown in Designer
HVL: https://imgur.com/NqqvJwq
Peak: http://imgur.com/6AvPyye

Comment: Have you tried adding stretch to the end of the layout? That will force the group boxes to their minimum height.

Comment: All of my GroupBoxes are arranged in a vertical layout with a vertical spacer at the bottom. The vertical spacer does its job keeping the GroupBoxes at their minimum size while they are expanded. I believe that something is increasing the minimum size of some of my GroupBoxes in their collapsed state, I just have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Have you considered creating a QWidget that is the sole child of the QGroupBox, and make your actual contents children of that QWidget? That way, you can hide/show the QWidget, and the layout of the contents does not need to be adjusted at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got back to this old code of mine some time ago and it appears that I finally came up with a reasonable solution. The complete code follows:

** CollapsibleGroupBox.h **

```
#ifndef COLLAPSIBLEGROUPBOX_H
#define COLLAPSIBLEGROUPBOX_H

#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QMap>
#include <QMargins>
#include <QPair>

class QResizeEvent;
class CollapseExpandButton;
class QSpacerItem;

class CollapsibleGroupBox : public QGroupBox
{
public:
  explicit CollapsibleGroupBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);

private:
  void resizeCollapseButton();
  void collapseLayout(QLayout *layout);
  void collapseSpacer(QSpacerItem *spacer);
  void expandLayout(QLayout *layout);
  void expandSpacer(QSpacerItem *spacer);

  CollapseExpandButton *m_clExpButton;
  QMap<const void *, QMargins> m_layoutMargins;
  QMap<const void *, QPair<QSize, QSizePolicy>> m_spacerSizes;

private slots:
  void onScreenChanged();
  void onVisibilityChanged();

};

#endif // COLLAPSIBLEGROUPBOX_H
```

** CollapsibleGroupBox.cpp **

```
#include "collapsiblegroupbox.h"
#include "collapseexpandbutton.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QWindow>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

inline
QWindow *findWindowForWidget(const QWidget *widget)
{
  for (;;) {
    QWindow *wh = widget->window()->windowHandle();
    if (wh != nullptr)
      return wh;

    widget = qobject_cast<const QWidget *>(widget->parent());
    if (widget == nullptr)
      return nullptr;
  }
}

inline
QScreen * findScreenForWidget(const QWidget *widget)
{
  for (;;) {
    QWindow *wh = widget->window()->windowHandle();
    if (wh != nullptr) {
      QScreen *scr = wh->screen();
      if (scr != nullptr)
        return scr;
    }

    widget = qobject_cast<const QWidget *>(widget->parent());
    if (widget == nullptr)
      return nullptr;
  }
}

CollapsibleGroupBox::CollapsibleGroupBox(QWidget *parent) :
  QGroupBox(parent)
{
  m_clExpButton = new CollapseExpandButton(this);

  connect(m_clExpButton, &CollapseExpandButton::clicked, this, &CollapsibleGroupBox::onVisibilityChanged);

  QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [this] {
    auto wh = findWindowForWidget(this);
    if (wh != nullptr)
      connect(wh, &QWindow::screenChanged, this, &CollapsibleGroupBox::onScreenChanged);
  });

  QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &CollapsibleGroupBox::resizeCollapseButton);
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::collapseLayout(QLayout *lay)
{
  assert(!m_layoutMargins.contains(lay));

  const int cnt = lay->count();
  for (int idx = 0; idx < cnt; idx++) {
    auto lit = lay->itemAt(idx);

    if (lit->widget()) {
      auto w = lit->widget();
      if (w != m_clExpButton)
        w->setVisible(false);
    }
    else if (lit->spacerItem())
      collapseSpacer(lit->spacerItem());
    else if (lit->layout())
      collapseLayout(lit->layout());
  }

  m_layoutMargins[lay] = lay->contentsMargins();
  lay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::collapseSpacer(QSpacerItem *spacer)
{
  assert(!m_spacerSizes.contains(spacer));

  m_spacerSizes[spacer] = {spacer->sizeHint(), spacer->sizePolicy()};
  spacer->changeSize(0, 0);
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::expandLayout(QLayout *lay)
{
  assert(m_layoutMargins.contains(lay));

  const int cnt = lay->count();
  for (int idx = 0; idx < cnt; idx++) {
    auto lit = lay->itemAt(idx);

    if (lit->widget())
      lit->widget()->setVisible(true);
    else if (lit->spacerItem())
      expandSpacer(lit->spacerItem());
    else if (lit->layout())
      expandLayout(lit->layout());
  }

  lay->setContentsMargins(m_layoutMargins[lay]);
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::expandSpacer(QSpacerItem *spacer)
{
  assert(m_spacerSizes.contains(spacer));

  const auto &sz = m_spacerSizes[spacer].first;
  const auto &pol = m_spacerSizes[spacer].second;

  spacer->changeSize(sz.width(), sz.height(), pol.horizontalPolicy(), pol.verticalPolicy());
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::onScreenChanged()
{
  resizeCollapseButton();
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::onVisibilityChanged()
{
  assert(this->layout() != nullptr);

  CollapseExpandButton::State s = m_clExpButton->state();

  switch (s) {
  case CollapseExpandButton::State::COLLAPSED:
    m_layoutMargins.clear();
    m_spacerSizes.clear();

    collapseLayout(this->layout());
    break;
  case CollapseExpandButton::State::EXPANDED:
    expandLayout(this->layout());
    break;
  }
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::resizeCollapseButton()
{
  const QScreen *scr = findScreenForWidget(this);

  if (scr == nullptr)
    return;

  const auto &size = this->size();

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
  qreal baseSize = 15.0;
  int yOffset = 5;
#else
  qreal baseSize = 22.0;
  int yOffset = 0;
#endif

  if (scr == nullptr)
    return;

  if (QString::compare(QApplication::style()->objectName(), "fusion") == 0)
    baseSize = 15.0;

  const qreal dpi = scr->logicalDotsPerInchX();
  const qreal btnSize = floor((baseSize * dpi / 96.0) + 0.5);

  m_clExpButton->setGeometry(size.width() - btnSize, yOffset, btnSize, btnSize);
}

void CollapsibleGroupBox::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
  resizeCollapseButton();
}
```

This seems to collapse and restore the boxes exactly as I would expect.

Comment: Could you please provide the missing source for collapseexpandbutton aswell

Comment: You can implement a CollapseExpandButton inheriting from QToolButton (checkable). There you can store the State (COLLAPSED or EXPANDED), connect to the clicked() signal and update the internal State in a slot like follows:
<code>
void CollapseExpandButton::onClicked(bool checked) {
    _state = checked ? EXPANDED : COLLAPSED;
    blockSignals(true);
    emit(clicked(checked));
    blockSignals(false);
}
</code>
Or if you like you can discard the State at all and use directly "m_clExpButton->isChecked()" insted of "m_clExpButton->state()" in CollapsibleGroupBox::onVisibilityChanged().

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the spacers you mentioned that are in the groupbox. Set their height to zero; it shouldn't affect their behaviour when the groupbox is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an explanation for the apparently non-reproducible height of the group box. But you could also just do something like this:

```
void CollapsibleGroupBox::onVisibilityChanged(bool state)
{
    switch (state) {
    case true:
        m_originalMaxHeight = this->maximumHeight();
        this->setMaximumHeight(this->fontMetrics().height());
        break;
    case false:
        this->setMaximumHeight(m_originalMaxHeight);
        break;
    }
}
```

and add a stretch to the layout containing the group box. It resizes nicely when dynamically adding or removing widgets.
[image: Collapsible group box]